# Calling Different Functions using doGet()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script was provided to me from Tanaike as an answer to the earlier question posted by me [Changing Owner of the Sheet irrespective of the duplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666605/changing-owner-of-the-sheet-irrespective-of-the-duplicator)
. and it worked wonderfully 
Now, I need to call different functions and run the same as Admin on user's spreadsheet but I am getting confused in how to call them depending on the function name or any other parameter.

The existing code is:

```js
function doGet() {
  script();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}

function Protect() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

// DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for the access token.
}

// This script is the same with your "Protect".
function script() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var totalSheets = countSheets(); //script function
  myValue = "DO" + totalSheets;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
  var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('C2:E5'), spreadsheet.getRange('C6:D7'), spreadsheet.getRange('F5:G6'), spreadsheet.getRange('B9:G18'), spreadsheet.getRange('G7:G8')])
    .removeEditors(['user1.com', 'user2.com', 'user3.com']);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').setValue(myValue);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-YYYY');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H1:H').clearContent();

};
```

Now, I want to call my created function `altrows()` to run when a specific button is clicked by the user and want it to run just like the above `script()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I confirm whether my understanding of your question is correct? In your situation, there are 2 buttons in the Spreadsheet. You want to run each function for each button using the workaround. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, now I remembered [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64673622/7108653). I think that this thread might be useful for your this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can achieve this with URL parameters.*

#### More Information:

When calling your web app, you can specify URL parameters at the end of the script URL in the form `?key=value` and then process these in your `doGet(e)` as properties of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.function == "script") {
    script();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  }
  else if (e.parameter.function == "altrows") {
    altrows(e.parameter.sheetName);
  }
  else { // do something by default if there are no url parameters
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  }
}
```

And then you can call the web app with the funcitons like so:

```
const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?function=";

// if you want to call function script():
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "script", {
                    headers: {
                      authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
                    }
                  });

// if you want to call function altrows():
// remember to also pass the sheet name as a url parameter

var sheetToRunOn = "Sheet1";
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "altrows&sheetName=" + sheetToRunOn, {
                    headers: {
                      authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
                    }
                  });
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Query string - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Thanks Rafa for the answer. This script helped me to get to run the desired function. Can you please let me know if I can pass sheetname with altrows() function.

Comment: Absolutely, you can also specify the sheet name with a URL parameter. I updated my answer.