# Google App Script fails when run as webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have shared a Google Sheet with another user and I want them to be able to run some script functions as the owner (me).

I have looked at these two topics:

[Google Sheets - Run script with Sheet Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673622/google-sheets-run-script-with-sheet-protection)

[Calling Different Functions using doGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710747/calling-different-functions-using-doget?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I am not having success. This is my error: "Exception: Request failed for https://script.google.com returned code 404."

Here is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('myMenu')
      .addItem('run function 1', 'function1')
      .addItem('run function 2', 'function2')
      .addItem('run webApp function 1', 'runfunction1')
      .addItem('run webApp function 2', 'runfunction2')
      .addToUi();
};

function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.run == "function1") {
    function1();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("run 1");
  }
  else if (e.parameter.run == "function2") {
    function2();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("run 2");
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Oops...no match found");
  }
};

function function1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("One");
  ss.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue(1);
};

function function2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("One");
  ss.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue(2);
};

function runfunction1() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function1";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};

function runfunction2() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function2";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};
```

And here is my spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Qucgafsv3jVljaCijrOFro9CSRBYZefilsQUjI5fuA/edit?usp=sharing)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If your actual script is the same as your showing script, I guess that the scope is not enough for requesting Web Apps. In this case, for example, a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is required to be included.
- In your script, when `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` is run, it returns the invalid URL. This has already been reported to the Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235862472)

When these points are reflected in your script, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Add a scope

Please add a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

In this case, please add a comment line to your script as follows.

##### From:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('myMenu')
      .addItem('run function 1', 'function1')
      .addItem('run function 2', 'function2')
      .addItem('run webApp function 1', 'runfunction1')
      .addItem('run webApp function 2', 'runfunction2')
      .addToUi();
};
```

##### To:

```js
// DriveApp.getFiles() // Please add this comment line. By this, a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" is automatically added by the script editor, when the script is run.

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('myMenu')
      .addItem('run function 1', 'function1')
      .addItem('run function 2', 'function2')
      .addItem('run webApp function 1', 'runfunction1')
      .addItem('run webApp function 2', 'runfunction2')
      .addToUi();
};
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps as new version

Please deploy Web Apps as a new version. And please copy the Web Apps URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. This URL is used instead of `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`.

#### 3. Modify your script as follows

##### From:

```js
function runfunction1() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function1";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};

function runfunction2() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function2";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};
```

##### To:

```js
function runfunction1() {
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Modified
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function1";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};

function runfunction2() {
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Modified
  fixedURL = url + "?run=function2";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fixedURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
};
```

#### 4. Redeploy Web Apps as the same version

After you modify `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` to `"https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"`, please redeploy Web Apps as the same version. In this case, you can see my report ["Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)"](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43).

**In your situation, when you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**

#### 5. Testing

After the above flow, please run `runfunction1` and `runfunction2`. By this, the script works. Also, I confirmed that the modified script worked.

#### Note:

- If an error occurs or `runfunction1` and `runfunction2` was not run after the above flow was done, please confirm the above flow again.
- By the way, from your showing script, in this modification, it supposes your Web Apps setting as follows.

  - `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account`, and your Spreadsheet is shared with the user.
  - If your setting of them is, `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`, I think that you are not required to use the access token.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you. You are so kind. I hardcoded the URL and this solved my problem.

Comment: @Boof Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.