# How can I duplicate and rename a spreadsheet using a Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script which I found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89986/duplicate-and-rename-sheet-in-one-action-on-google-sheets) which mimicks the 'make a copy' function, but also renames the sheet all within a single action.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Duplicate and name", functionName: "dupName"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function dupName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter new sheet name');
  ss.insertSheet(name, {template: sheet});
}
```

I want to take this script a step farther and use it to increase the number in the name of the previous sheet, by 1.

For example, A sheet will be called 'Sheet 1' and when I duplicate the sheet using this script, I want the new one to be called 'Sheet 2'.

Is this possible?
If so, how can I modify this script to do that?
Or is there a better way to write it in the first place?
(considering the post I'm referencing to is 4 years old).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script can duplicate the sheets and also rename the same with your custom name and add protection to either selected range or complete sheet as defined in the protection line:

```js
function script() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var totalSheets = countSheets(); //script function
  myValue = "CUSTOMTEXT" + totalSheets; //sample CUSTOMTEXT1
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
  var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('C2:E5')])
    .removeEditors(['user1@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com']);
  protection.addEditor('user0@gmail.com');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};

function countSheets() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().length;
}
```

If the same function is triggered using the doget(e) function you can be the owner of the sheet irrespective to the triggering user. Kindly follow the following for more details on it: [Changing Owner of the Sheet irrespective of the duplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666605/changing-owner-of-the-sheet-irrespective-of-the-duplicator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Duplicate and name", functionName: "dupName"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function dupName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var array = sheet.getName().split(" ");
  var ssnum = Number(array[array.length-1]);
  array[array.length-1] = ++ssnum;
  ss.insertSheet(array.join(' '), {template: sheet});
}
```

Note that you need to have a space delimiter between the text part and the number part of the sheet name in order to use this script.

Sample Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: This looks like it does exactly what I want it to do!
How do I go about triggering it?

Comment: The ````onOpen()```` function creates a menu called ````Custom```` with the option ````Duplicate and Name````. You can then trigger the script using the created menu.

Comment: Oh! The menu option didn't come up for me for some reason, I just reloaded the document and I saw it and it works absolutely beautifully. This really is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a way of having 2 options in the menu where one makes it a protected sheet than only I can edit too?